# Live Notifications using JQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, mysqli

I am using CodeIgniter, basically I have a table which has dummy data, and I am returning this data using jQuery.

I do this by:

Controller:

```
class Notifications extends CI_Controller{
        function getAlerts(){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ID, subject, message, readMessage FROM data WHERE readMessage = 0");
            $result = $query->num_rows();

            if($result > 0){
                return $result;
                echo $result;
            }   
        }
```

Header Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        getMessageCount1();
      });
      function getMessageCount1() {
        $('div#alertsfrommydb').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>notifications/getAlerts').fadeIn();
        setTimeout("getMessageCount1()", 10000);
      }
   </script>
```

and the view as such:

```
<div id="alertsfrommydb">
    </div>
```

I have a method which is called showAlerts() in the same controller which prints a table and shows my messages refreshing every 10 seconds, and this works perfectly fine using above approach.

In addition I have a method called notifications.php and I load this in my controller, which then allows me to simply in my view type:

```
print_r($this->notifications->getAlerts());
```

And the query shows my results fine which is '6' meaning I have 6 unread messages.

So my argument is, the query is working, so why will it not work using the jQuery approach.

Although my query works, I have a gut feeling there is something not right about it lol, hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a ajax call anywhere in you code?

Comment: Erm the script in the header? If this is not ajax then my apologies, what would this be? @noob

Answer (score 2):

No you are doing it wrong! the ajax call in codeigniter looks something like this:

```
function getMessageCount1() {

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '<?php echo base_url()."/notifications/getAlerts"?>',
     data: { NumberOfAlerts:result of your query }, 
     success:function(response){
        $('#alertsfrommydb').html(response);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have now edited my post changing it from ajax to jQuery, FYI I have tried above approach and used the script to load ajax, still no luck :(

Comment: can you edit the original post with what you have tried with ajax

Comment: have already done that, I haven't tried anything with ajax, realised it was all jQuery @noob

Comment: I really appreciate your help and support, I've just tried what you suggested....... still no luck :.(

Comment: did you add json encode to the passed string ion notifications.php? like this $alerts =($this->notifications->getAlerts()); echo json_encode($alerts);